# Installation of required component pre-required modules and features for SharePoint 2010

Tags: installation, prerequisites

I'v installed SharePoint many times.

But today when install all of the pre required SharePoint not installed

[image: setup errors unable to proceed due to the following error windows server features or roles services required by this product are note enables]

error:

> setup errors : unable to proceed due to the following error : windows server features or Role services required by this product are not enabled. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=106209

[image: system information]

list of Components that we Installed:

[image: pre-requisites]

[image: dot net framework and iis]

Comment: Go to Server Manager -> Roles -> make sure Web Server (IIS) and Application Server roles are there! Also, go to Features -> make sure .Net Framework 3.5.1 Features is installed

Comment: step 1 I installed them. installed but error occur.

Comment: Application Server role is also installed? What is the error when you install the roles?

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri also same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Server has a static IP address and its a domain controller (Installed active directory and DNS services) without any error then you should be able to make it a Web Server, don't think if application server is necessity. Anyway it seems like someone else had [same problem, but if you go through comments someone solved problem by resetting environmental variables because of permissions issue.](http://sharepointnomad.wordpress.com/2010/07/23/installing-sharepoint-2010-on-windows-server-2008-r2-which-server-roles-and-features-do-i-need/)

Also check if there's any error in event viewer.

**EDIT**

After looking at logs, problem is that your server where you are trying to install SharePoint isn't able to connect to remote domain controller, I would suggest you to go through this link, I am pretty sure it will work :)

http://www.administrator.de/forum/windows-2008-dcom-was-unable-to-communicate-with-the-computer-pc-meinedomain-com-using-any-of-the-configured-protocols-120415.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: i have dedicated active directory server

Comment: oh I see, is there any other errors in event viewer

Comment: DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer . using any of the configured protocols.

Comment: The removal of the assignment of application Microsoft Office Excel MUI (English) 2007 from policy Default Domain Policy failed.  The error was : %%2

Comment: Driver PDF-XChange 3.0 required for printer PDF-XChange 3.0 is unknown. Contact the administrator to install the driver before you log in again.

Comment: Event filter with query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 60 WHERE TargetInstance ISA "Win32_Processor" AND TargetInstance.LoadPercentage > 99" could not be reactivated in namespace "//./root/CIMV2" because of error 0x80041003. Events cannot be delivered through this filter until the problem is corrected.

Comment: nothing else ...

Comment: that is enough, I updated my answer

Comment: This is a German article ! can you summarize it here? in English?

Comment: do you have chrome ? it will translate it to english automatically :)

Comment: yes i have. and translate and i apply those troubleshooting instructions but i have still same errors! ( i want to find this page for others by more keywords)

Comment: could you help me? my problem not solved

Comment: Since its problem with network connectivity I am afraid I will be able to help u a lot, but I find another article that might help, http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-networking/dcom-was-unable-to-communicate-with-the-computer/de6ccd26-b40e-495d-9201-55055b7b4c4e,

if this doesn't work either, I would suggest you to try to ask question on http://serverfault.com/ hope it helps :).

Comment: i disjoin and join it again and dont have any connectivity problem. that error may relate to another thing. can u see other errors?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/461746/installation-of-required-component-pre-required-modules-and-features-for-sharepo

Answer (score 1):

strange. My DVD image doesnt have SQL Server and i should install that. when install it then installation is OK and .... then SharePoint and Project Server installed